# read from file 50 chars at a time C#

Tags: c#, file, file-io

I´m starting to use C# and there is a question that i´m trying to solve for the last coople of days with no success.....

I´d like to read a file and instead of reading line by line, i´d like to define the size of that line(eg 50 chars) and save it.

SO the result will be

```
lines[0] = "first block of 50 chars" ---- 0to50

lines[1] = "second block of 50 chars"-----50to100
```

and so on

I´ve tried

```
        using (StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(path))
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                int c = fs.Read();
                char sC = (char)c;


            }

        }
```

All i can do is read the first 50 chars from the file i need to put them together in a string, right?
Can you help me with that?

EDIT : if the file is larger then 50 the rest should go to the next itemin array
the file is a txt or similar format.

Comment: What have you tried?  What difficulties have you encountered?  Can you read a single byte?

Comment: Try FileStream.Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @user3061846 - Please edit and update your question with what you have tried, instead of adding that information to comments.

Comment: if a line is longer than 50 lines, should we ignore it? Or should the rest of the line go to next item in array?

Comment: Why is 50 character read needed? Are you pulling up a 1 gig file? If you are not, playing OS and trying to read a file in chunks may  not be the way to do this, for the file IO methods are optimized for these situations already.

Comment: what i need is to split a file in blocks of 50 char (or another number), and save all this blocks. if the line is longer than 50 the rst should go to next item in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simple way would be using Linq

```
int inx = 0;
var lines50 = File.ReadAllText(fname)
                .GroupBy(_ => inx++ / 50)
                .Select(x => new string(x.ToArray()))
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Good solution for small files. You will need something else for ~100 MB and up.